# How to replace UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Using XML configuration would be like

```
<custom-filter position="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER" ref="SCAAuthenticationFilter" />.
```

Without XML would be like:

```
httpSecurity.addFilter(new SCAAthenticationFilter())
```

It seems that spring doesn't replace **UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter**, but adds my filter before.

Comment: Does your SCAAuthenticationFilter class extend UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter?

Comment: Yes, SCAAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter

Comment: My solution was not to replace the UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter but adding before it. I also needed to change the form action from /login to /j_security_check, username to j_username and password to j_password. Thereby my custom filter was called succesfully.

Answer (score 3):

If you take a look to *FormLoginConfigurer* you will see that the *UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter* is created and inserted to *AbstractAuthenticationFilterConfigurer* constructor then there it is assigned to *final F authFilter* so there is no way to replace it in Spring Security 4.1

*addFilter()* will simply add another filter to filter list

Answer (score 2):

I'd guess you must have either had `<form-login>` or had `<http auto-config="true">` in your configuration. Unless either of these are present, Spring Security won't add a `UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter` automatically. The URL for submitting the form and the parameter names are all configurable properties of the filter, which your custom version didn't override, hence the difference.